# Trying to write Fibonacci sequence in scala, where is my code going wrong?

Tags: scala

I am going through a course on Udemy to learn Spark and I am totally new to scala and recursive programming. When I try to get a return from this loop in the .sc editor in eclipse, I get no output to the right. I can provide more context if that helps.

```
 var prev2 = 0
 var prev1 = 1
 for (y <- 1 to 10){
            var g : Int = prev1 + prev2
            var prev2 : Int = prev1
            var prev1 : Int = g
            println(g)
            }
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile.

Comment: There is no recursion here, what does this have to do with recursive programming?

Answer (score 0):

You declared variables `prev1` and `prev2` twice. Second declarations between `{...}` hid there the first ones and compiler thought that in the line `var g : Int = prev1 + prev2` you referred to the `prev1` and `prev2` declared later. So compiler wrote error message about "forward reference".

The easiest way to fix your code is:

```
var prev2: Int = 0
var prev1: Int = 1
for (y <- 1 to 10){
  var g : Int = prev1 + prev2
  prev2 = prev1
  prev1 = g
  println(g)
}
```

This is surely besides the fact that this is not kind of [recursive programming](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-recursion-examples-recursive-programming).

Comment: @GregCarnovale 
If you're satisfied with my answer you can accept it.

You can start learning Scala and functional programming with tutorials:
[1](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/scala/),
[2](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala/),
[3](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/functional_programming/).
Other learning resources are listed here:
[1](https://blog.codacy.com/how-to-learn-scala-cb53c5eb5ff6),
[2](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-learn-Scala),
[3](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/tour-of-scala.html).

Comment: the answer is wrong it outputs 1,2,3 ,,, instead of 0,1,1

Comment: @YKY It's not wrong. 1,2,3,5,8,13,... are correct Fibonacci numbers, just shifted. https://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C3%2C5%2C8%2C13&language=english&go=Search

Comment: @YKY My answer was not about how to calculate Fibonacci numbers. It was about how OP can fix compilation.

Answer (score 0):

Just so that you know ... Fibonacci in actual real scala would look something like this:

```
lazy val fs: Stream[Long] = 0 #:: 1  #:: fs.zip(fs.tail).map { case(a,b) => a + b }
fs.take(11).map(println)
```

If you are going to use vars an loops, scala is an overkill, there is plenty of languages that are much better suited for that style.

Comment: Or something like this: `0 #:: fs.scan(1L)(_+_)`

Comment: yeah .. haven't thought of that, it's even better.